# add uniqueness to a table column just for some cases in mysql using knex

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

I'm using mysql. I want a column to have unique values just in some cases.

Example, the table can have the next vales:

```
 +----+-----------+----------+------------+
 | id | user_id   | col1     | col2       |
 +----+-----------+----------+------------+
 |  1 |         2 | no       | no         |
 |  2 |         2 | no       | no         |
 |  3 |         3 | no       | yes        |
 |  4 |         2 | yes      | no         |
 |  5 |         2 | no       | yes        |
 +----+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I want the no|no to be able to repeat for the same user but no the yes|no combination. Is this possible in mysql? And with knex?

My migration fot that table looks like this

```
return knex.schema.createTable('myTable', table => {
    table.increments('id').unsigned().primary();
    table.integer('uset_id').unsigned().notNullable().references('id').inTable('table_user').onDelete('CASCADE').index();
    table.string('col1').defaultTo('yes');
    table.string('col2').defaultTo('no');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem to be easy task to do. You would need partial unique index over multiple columns.

I couldn't spot that mysql would support partial indexes https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

So it could Something like what is described here, but using triggers for that seems a bit overkill https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41030/creating-a-partial-unique-constraint-for-mysql